# Drupal 7: Find which user created a given user

Tags: users

I have a number of users admins (group: "**users_admin**") who create users who can view content (in many groups, like "**students_a**", "**students_b**", "**students_c**", and so on).

Is there a way to filter the users by their creators?

Let me clarify:

- User "**A**" from "**users_admin**" create a user "**S1**" in "**students_a**".
- User "**B**" from "**users_admin**" creates a user "**S2**" in "**students_a**".

I would like to be able to differentiate users created by "A" and "B", has anyone done that before? Is it possible?

I hope I made myself clear enough; please tell me if you need some clarifications.

Thanks in advance for you insights!
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Drupal, by default, does not keep any authoring information of users.

However, there is a module for that! Try [Sub User](http://drupal.org/project/subuser) module. It uses Relation module to maintain the relationship with parent user.